# I am doing a re.findall a string and I get an error of: error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python

Good afternoon, I have the following string that I get after making an ssh query through a team using paramiko, I get the string in the variable "buff_config" and I want to know how many times the expression "* B: P79COL01 # $" is found inside from it, but in doing so I get the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
>       220 
>       221     Empty matches are included in the result."""
>   --> 222     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
>       223 
>       224 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
>       299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
>       300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
>   --> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
>       302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
>       303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
>       560     if isstring(p):
>       561         pattern = p
>   --> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
>       563     else:
>       564         pattern = None
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
>       853 
>       854     try:
>   --> 855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
>       856     except Verbose:
>       857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state,
>   verbose, nested)
>       414     while True:
>       415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
>   --> 416                            not nested and not items))
>       417         if not sourcematch("|"):
>       418             break
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state,
>   verbose, nested, first)
>       614             if not item or (_len(item) == 1 and item[0][0] is AT):
>       615                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
>   --> 616                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
>       617             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
>       618                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",
>
> error: nothing to repeat at position 0

The code I use is as follows:

```
re.findall('*B:P79COL01#$',buff_config)
```

buff_config variable :

[image]

excuse me but I could place what the buff_config variable includes, since I don't leave the question editor

Comment: `*B:P79COL01#` is the device's prompt. Why do you expect it to be contained more than twice in the string?

Comment: Your regex starts with an astrix. An astrixi is used to indicate 0 or more occurances or some match. You need to put a backslash to remove the special meaning so its treated as a literal

Comment: Is this an XY problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in regex means "repeat what comes before it 0 or more times" so it can't be the first character, which is what the error tries to tell you.

You can escape it (`\*`) in order to search for literal `*` characters, but you don't even need regex. You can just use `buff_config.count('*B:P79COL01#')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex starts with an astrix which is used to indicate 0 or more instances or a pattern. However looking at your source you want a literal astrix so you need to prefix it with a backslash to tell the regex to ignore the special meaning of `*` and look for it as a literal char in the string

```
re.findall(r'\*B:P79COL01#$',buff_config)
```